# Simple text cleaning python 3.6 script not giving correct output on executing the script using cmd prompt on windows 10

Tags: python, regex, windows, unicode, windows-10

This script runs perfectly when I executed it on `spyder` but same script isn't giving correct output when I execute the script through command prompt on my Windows 10 machine. I have python 3.6 and anaconda 3.6 on my machine. It's really weird behaviour. I tried to execute the script on an ubuntu system too but didn't get the correct output on it either.

**clean_data.py**

```
import re
import argparse

def main(data):
    if data.strip():
        data = data.strip()
        emoji_pattern = re.compile("["
                "\U0001F600-\U0001F64F"  # emoticons
                "\U0001F000-\U0001F5FF"  # symbols & pictographs
                "\U0001F680-\U0001F6FF"  # transport & map symbols
                "\U0001F1E0-\U0001F1FF"  # flags (iOS)
                "\U0001F900-\U0001F9FF"  # extra emoticons
                "\U00002600-\U000026FF"
                "\U00002700-\U000027BF"
                "\U00002B00-\U00002BFF"
                "\U00003000-\U000032FF"
                "\U000025A0-\U000025FF"
                "\U000024C2-\U0001F251"
                "\U000020D0-\U000120FF"
                "\U00000000-\U0000001a"
                "]+", flags=re.UNICODE)
        data = emoji_pattern.sub("", data)
        data = re.sub("[^A-Za-z0-9 !@#$%^&*()_+=-}]{[|\':;?/>.<,]", "", data).encode("ascii", "ignore").decode("utf-8")
        print(data)
    else:
        print("Empty string!!")

#main("     ")
#main("i'm deciding between Firestik Firefly, 4' \u2248\u001a200w, \n\r& Firestik FS-3BK, 3' \u2248\u001a650w. Is one better? It's for recreational use on and off road. thank you!")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    description = __doc__,
    formatter_class = argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter)
    parser.add_argument('data', help = 'Simply the text that you want to clean.')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    main(args.data)
```

To reproduce, save the script as "clean_data.py"

To execute the script open terminal and type:

> python clean_data.py "i'm deciding between Firestik Firefly, 4' \u2248\u001a200w, \n\r& Firestik FS-3BK, 3' \u2248\u001a650w. Is one better? It's for recreational use on and off road. thank you!"

The expected output is:

> i'm deciding between Firestik Firefly, 4' 200w, & Firestik FS-3BK, 3' 650w. Is one better? It's for recreational use on and off road. thank you!

Comment: Reproduced on OS X python 3.6.

Comment: Did you get the correct output through terminal @cdarke?

Comment: The command prompt doesn't translate \u2248 for example into a Unicode character.  It is literally six ASCII characters.  That is Python syntax, not shell syntax.

Comment: @ShubhamChandra: no, I get the same output as you do.

Comment: Hey @MarkTolonen Thnx for your explanation. It is really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cmd shell doesn't understand Python's Unicode escape sequences, so you are receiving literal ASCII characters for the escape codes.

If you want to support translating them, you could change you `main` call to:

```
main(args.data.encode(sys.stdin.encoding).decode('unicode-escape'))
```

And then your output will be:

```
i'm deciding between Firestik Firefly, 4' 200w, & Firestik FS-3BK, 3' 650w. Is one better? It's for recreational use on
and off road. thank you!
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @MarkTolonen for this solution. It explained everything clearly and most importantly, it worked!