# Decoding Unicode Characters > U+1f900 doesn't work without print

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode

When I try to decode unicode charaters like this:

```
>>> x = '\\U0000263a'
>>> x.encode().decode('unicode-escape')
'☺'
```

It works! but it fails for greater than U+1f900.

```
>>> x = '\\U0001f941'
>>> x.encode().decode('unicode-escape')
'\U0001f941'

>>> x = '\\U0001f900'
>>> x.encode().decode('unicode-escape')
'\U0001f900'
```

But when print it, it works!

```
>>> x = '\\U0001f901'
>>> print(x.encode().decode('unicode-escape'))
```

Can anyone explain to me what's going on?
I am using python 3.5.2

Comment: related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49339739/simple-text-cleaning-python-3-6-script-not-giving-correct-output-on-executing-th)

Comment: @Prateek   x.encode(sys.stdin.encoding).decode('unicode-escape') is not working for me.

Comment: my `sys.stdin.encoding` = 'UTF-8' FYI

Comment: I get an error on py 3.5 are you?  "UnicodeEncodeError: 'UCS-2' codec can't encode character '\U0001f941' in position 0: Non-BMP character not supported in Tk"

Comment: Note the `\\U` @ZackTarr

Comment: I do get drum for '\\U0001f941' with python 3.6.5

Comment: With or without print?

Comment: I tried this on https://repl.it with python 3.6.1 but the same results.

Comment: @Prateek can you be more specific about your comments. Your comments are very unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are trying to visualize the emojis .The output is expected in Python.

Please check official [Unicode mappings](http://www.unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html) with Emojis

**U+1F901** and **U+1F900** dont have assigned emoji mapping

In Python 3.6.5

```
u'\U0001F941'
''
```

If you want fancy printing I found [`emoji`](https://github.com/carpedm20/emoji/blob/master/emoji/unicode_codes.py) library with huge mapping and visually good displays 
Please note I did not use encode and decode

```
import emoji
emoji.emojize(':drum:')
''
```

However U+1F901 is [**Circled Cross Formee With Two Dots**](https://unicode-table.com/en/1F901/)
and U+1F900 is **Circled Cross Formee With Four Dots**  which dont have standard display mappings on Unicode.org page.

Comment: But clearly [U+1f941](http://www.unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html#1f941) does.

Comment: Also, this is not what I asked.

Comment: It's very unclear how you are achieving the drum you show. Are you using print statement? Please post the full code.

Comment: I am using gnome-terminal. What are you using?

Comment: its on pycharm's python console.